# Different closures giving different results for retain cycles in swift

Tags: swift, retain-cycle

I am reading Apple's Swift Programming Language Guide. In the part about Strong Reference Cycle for closures, I tried a different type of closure but it did not give the expected output.

```
class HTMLElement {

let name: String
let text: String?

lazy var asHTML : String = {

    //[unowned self] in

    if let text = self.text {
        return "<\(self.name)>\(text)</\(self.name)>"
    } else {
        return "<\(self.name) />"
    }
}()

init(name: String, text: String? = nil) {
    self.name = name
    self.text = text
}

deinit {
    println("\(name) is being deinitialized")
}

}

 var paragraph: HTMLElement? = HTMLElement(name: "p", text: "hello, world")
 println(paragraph!.asHTML)
 paragraph = nil
```

The output of this code is :

```
<p>hello, world</p>
p is being deinitialized
```

"p is being deinitialised" is printed even without [unowned self]

The code in the guide is:

```
class HTMLElement {

let name: String
let text: String?

lazy var asHTML: () -> String = {
    [unowned self] in
    if let text = self.text {
        return "<\(self.name)>\(text)</\(self.name)>"
    } else {
        return "<\(self.name) />"
    }
}

init(name: String, text: String? = nil) {
    self.name = name
    self.text = text
}

deinit {
    println("\(name) is being deinitialized")
}

}
var paragraph: HTMLElement? = HTMLElement(name: "p", text: "hello, world")
 println(paragraph!.asHTML)
 paragraph = nil
```

This prints the deinitialiser message only when the [unowned self] statement is added.

What is the difference between both the closures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question! To explore it, we should simplify the test case to the minimum required to demonstrate it:

```
// First case, a lazy string
class LazyVar {
    let name = "LazyVar"
    lazy var lazyName : String = { return self.name }()
    deinit {
        println("\(name) is being deinitialized")
    }
}

var lazyVar: LazyVar? = LazyVar()
println(lazyVar?.lazyName)
lazyVar = nil // Calls deinit

// Second case, a lazy ()->String
class LazyFunc {
    let name = "LazyFunc"
    lazy var lazyFunc: () -> String = {
        // [unowned self] in    // <-- This would break the loop
        return self.name
    }
    deinit {
        println("\(name) is being deinitialized")
    }
}

var lazyFunc: LazyFunc? = LazyFunc()
println(lazyFunc?.lazyFunc())
lazyFunc = nil // Doesn't call deinit
```

In the first case, there is no permanent retain loop. When you access `lazyName`, a closure is evaluated `{ return self.name }`. That closure captures `self`, computes a string, and returns the string. The string is assigned to the property. We're now done with the closure, so it's released, and it releases `self`. Note that there is a brief retain loop here, but that's ok. It is eventually broken, and that's all that matters.

In the second case, there is a permanent retain loop. When you access `lazyFunc()`, it calls a closure that creates a *new closure*. That new closure is `{return self.name}`, and that is assigned to the property. And that closure retains `self`, so is a retain loop that is never broken. Adding `[unowned self] in` to `lazyFunc` as marked would break the loop for you.

Comment: Great answer @RobNapier ! Would be nice integrating it with the solution to the `LazyFunc` retain loop. I suppose it would be an `[unowned self] in` at the `lazyFunc`'s closure beginning. I see the question has it, but having it all in a sigle spot ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In the example from the Swift book, `asHTML` is a *closure*:

```
lazy var asHTML : () -> String = {
    if let text = self.text {
        return "<\(self.name)>\(text)</\(self.name)>"
    } else {
        return "<\(self.name) />"
    }
}
```

`self` holds a strong reference to the closure (via the `asHTML`
property), and the
closure holds a strong reference to `self`  (unless you add
`[unowned self]`).

In your example, `asHTML` is a property of type `String`:

```
lazy var asHTML : String = {
    if let text = self.text {
        return "<\(self.name)>\(text)</\(self.name)>"
    } else {
        return "<\(self.name) />"
    }
}()
```

The right-hand side is evaluated once, when the lazy property is accessed
the first time. A closure object is created (capturing `self`) and evaluated. After that, the closure object is destroyed (because no
strong references exist to it). In particular, the captured reference
to `self` is released: No closure anymore, no retain cycle.